# SKSpriteNodes not Appearing Properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to make a 'Pop the Lock' like game for a bit of fun and practice, but my SKSpriteNodes are not appearing at all. My GameScene.swift is below as well as my GameViewController.swift. I've looked at other people's projects using Sprite Kit and they all work fine but their code in mine just isn't working either.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

```
   import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

---

```
    import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var circle = SKSpriteNode()
    var tapper = SKSpriteNode()

    var tapperPath = UIBezierPath()

    var gameStarted = Bool()

    var movingClockwise = Bool()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
        circle.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        circle.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
        self.addChild(circle)

        tapper = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Tapper")
        tapper.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 7)
        tapper.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 120)
        tapper.zRotation = 3.14 / 2
        self.addChild(tapper)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if gameStarted {
            if movingClockwise {
                moveCounterClockWise()
                movingClockwise = false
            } else {
                moveClockWise()
                movingClockwise = true
            }
        } else {
            moveClockWise()
            movingClockwise = true
            gameStarted = true
        }
    }


    func moveClockWise() {

        let dx = tapper.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = tapper.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

        tapperPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + (CGFloat.pi * 4), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.follow(tapperPath.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        tapper.run(SKAction.repeatForever(follow).reversed())

    }

    func moveCounterClockWise() {

        let dx = tapper.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = tapper.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

        tapperPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + (CGFloat.pi * 4), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.follow(tapperPath.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        tapper.run(SKAction.repeatForever(follow))

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

### Edit

.sks file:

[image]

Comment: what are some symptoms? any errors or the sprites just don't show up? why don't you have a zPosition set on your sprites? try setting the zPosition and see if they show up

Comment: @RonMyschuk I haven't been getting any errors, they just don't show up. I've set the zPosition on both of them to 1.0 and 2.0 so the tapper is above the circle, still the same in the simulator.

Comment: Something's wrong in .sks file? Where did this black square comes from?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Nothing I believe. I've added an image of it to my main post.

Comment: @MaxKortge You need to find where does this black box comes from! From what you gave, it should not be there...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I know that but  as you said it shouldn't be there and I'm completely stuck with where to go.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I've found out the black box comes from when I add the circle as a child to the game scene on the did move and after removing adding it, I've just spotted the tapper moving in the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: Looks like you have problems loading the images... Number of nodes seems correct (didn't noticed that before: scene+two added nodes).